# Find All possible matches from string in php

Tags: php, string, find

I am working on search functionality in php.

I want to search for all possible combination from string.

#### Example: IF Search String is : BDS

Then It will Possible find for this all combination given below:

```
B D S
B S D

S B D
S D B

D S B
D B S
```

Example String In Which I want to Find:  **ABDBDBSNIEKDKLDJSDBJKDKDDSBJDJDK**

Comment: You can use [`str_shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-shuffle.php) on a loop adding to an array until you good all kinds of combinations based on a calculation of total possible combinations, but it won't be any performatic, tho.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown thanks for the suggestion I will tryit

Comment: Can i get why down vote??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just do one more step tricky to get all possible string to search in getPossibleStr($str)
Then you have to search in long string whihc you are look into.

```
$searchString = array_unique(getPossibleStr("DBS")); //Get All possible string in array
findString($searchString); //Here that array contains possible string to pass and check in your big string
function getPossibleStr($str) {
    if (strlen($str) < 2) {
        return array($str);
    }
    $permutations = array();
    $tail = substr($str, 1);
    foreach (getPossibleStr($tail) as $permutation) {
        $length = strlen($permutation);
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++) {
            $permutations[] = substr($permutation, 0, $i) . $str[0] . substr($permutation, $i);
        }
    }
    return $permutations;
}
function findString($searchString){
    $string = 'ABDBDBSNIEKDKLDJSDBJKDKDDSBJDJDK';
    $searchFlag = 0;
    foreach ($searchString as $searchStr) {
        if (strpos($string, $searchStr) !== FALSE) {
            echo "<br>Match found => ".$searchStr; 
            $searchFlag = 1;
        }
    }
    if($searchFlag == 0)
        echo "Not found!";
    }
}
```

Comment: my own code. I had been using this in my concept @DontVoteMeDown